# What effect would the transmooker have on people?

Tags: spy-kids

In the climax of *Spy Kids 2*, the bad guy fires the transmooker at the Gomezes, when

> Gregorio jumps in front of his parents in law intending to take a hit for them. But as it turns out, Gerti has disobeyed her father and has sabotaged the transmooker, causing it to misfire.

But since the transmooker's function is shutting down electronic devices, what would've been the effect on people? What effect did the bad guy *intend* it to have?

Comment: It transmooks you.

Comment: @amarillo [Captain Obvious to the rescue!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axtfB7QPTiw) :)

Comment: Was this bad guy known for being smart? Maybe he just picked up whatever was nearby and hoped that it would do something.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's similar to an [EMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_pulse), according to [this](http://dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a221552.pdf) it's unlikely there would be any noticable physiological effects from the "transmooking" itself, although according to a [more recent study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19725471) there may be some short lived effects in  the brain. Depending on how the pulse is generated there could be shockwaves, electrocution, or various types of penetrating radiation.